# Showing Listview in Fragment

Tags: java

I am a beginner in programming and am stuck working on my first ever project which will be a real motivation if I succeed.
I am trying to get my listview to show in my tabbed fragment. I have no errors but it is not showing neither crashing.
I have the public class tab1 extends fragment... and all tabs are showing fine and i can add even more but the listview is just not showing. I have checked out a few similar problem but being a begginer am still stuck and will be grateful for any professional help. Thats why am here. Kindly assist as i have this tabbed activity inside a nav drawer and would like the listview to be the third fragment. Thank you for your time

Comment: Show some code. Btw, If you are in first steps in java program the best idea is to starting with some tutorials. investing your time following a book or any good source will be more helpful than solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks. Could you help me go about showing the code. I am surely a beginner lol. Like steps guys use here are way so technical but eager to learn.

Comment: see this question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336269/posting-code-and-formatting and this one as well https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow